# Recursion explanation countdown function with multiple methods

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursion that will create a countdown array. The function should take an array in the `myArray` parameter and append the numbers `n` through 1 based on the `n` parameter. For example, calling this function with `n = 5` will pad the array with the numbers `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` inside of it. Your function must use recursion by calling itself and must not use loops of any kind.

Seems to be multiple ways to write a recursion, is there a generally accepted and easily readable method?

```
function countdown(myArray, n){
  if (n>=1) {
     myArray = countdown(myArray, n-1);
     myArray.unshift(n);
  }
  return myArray;
}


function countdown(myArray, n){
 if (n<=0) {
   return;
 } else {
   myArray.push(n);
   countdown(myArray,n-1);
 }
}
```

If I enter `countdown(myArray, 5)`, both functions returns an array called `myArray = [5,4,3,2,1]`.

The bottom function has a typical base case... while the top function doesn't? I'm  more comfortable writing it using the bottom method but I'm kind of confused why it works. Wouldn't bottom function be calling until it gets to `countdown(myArray,0)`, then return and start going back up the stack. So wouldn't it start with `myArray.push(1)` before it works its way back up the stack causing the answer to be `[1,2,3,4,5]` instead of `[5,4,3,2,1]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you add an else branch into the first function, and move the return into both branches (thus not changing the meaning):

```
 if (n>=1) {
   myArray = countdown(myArray, n-1);
   myArray.unshift(n);
   return myArray;
 } else {
   return myArray;
 }
```

Now invert the if statement (swapping both the condition and the branches):

```
 if(n <= 0) {
   return myArray; 
 } else {
   myArray = countdown(myArray, n-1);
   myArray.unshift(n);
   return myArray;
 }
```

So as you can see, both functions are *equal*, as they can be transformed i to each other without making breaking changes (however one does return `myArray` while the other one does not).

Now *wheres the base case* in the first function? Well, if `n` is 0 or less, it does not enter the `if` and as the recursive call is inside the `if`s branch ... it does not call itself again.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that having `return myArray` inside the `else` statement cause entire function to exit?